# how to use EF to store a data from a json body

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I wanted to store some JSON data to a database using Entity Framework.

This here is my JSON:

```
{
    "BrandId": 488,
    "PropDetail": {
        "LicenceNumber": "123",
        "InsuranceNumber": "456",
        "PostalCode": "4AN"
    },
    "Drivers": [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "LicenceNumber": "123",
            "InsuranceNumber": "456",
            "PostalCode": "4AN"
        }
    ]
}
```

There will be multiple driver details in the JSON.

The saved data should be like this:

[image]

This is my table structure:

```
Id, BrandId, PropDetail, DriversDetail
```

I am trying to save the data and from request to entity class mapping.

My entity class is as follows:

```
public class DriverInfo : IdEntityBase
{
    public virtual int DriverInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BrandId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProposerDetails PropDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<DriverDetails> DriverDetails { get; set; }
}

var driverInfo = new DriverInfo()
            {
                BrandId = request.BrandId,
                ProposerDetails = new ProposerDetails()
                {
                    DriverId = 1,
                    PostalCode =  request.PropDetail.PostalCode,
                    LicenceNumber = request.PropDetail.LicenceNumber,
                    InsuranceNumber = request.PropDetail.InsuranceNumber 
                },
                DriverDetails = request.Drivers.Select(x => new DriverDetails() 
                { 
                    DriverId = x.Id,
                    LicenceNumber = x.LicenceNumber,
                    InsuranceNumber = x.NationalInsuranceNumber,
                    PostalCode = x.PostalCode 
                })
            };
            Repository.Save(driverInfo);
```

I added this `DbSet` for the entity to my `Dbcontext`:

```
public DbSet<DriverInfo> DriverInfo { get; set; }
```

When I try to save the data, I'm getting the following exception:

> The type of navigation property 'DriverDetails' on the entity type 'DriverInfo' is 'SelectListIterator<DriverDetails, DriverDetails>' which does not implement ICollection

Comment: How are the types `DriverInfo` and `DriverDetails` related? Did you mean to have the Navigation `public virtual IEnumerable<DriverInfo> DriverDetails { get; set; }` ? (And I'd make that an `ICollection` as Qing Guo suggests in his answer, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ICollection` as a navigation property:

```
public ICollection<DriverDetails>  DriverDetails { get; set; }
```

And  use `ToList()` before you save the data, like:

```
 DriverDetails = request.Drivers.Select(x => new DriverDetails() 
                { 
                    DriverId = x.Id,
                    LicenceNumber = x.LicenceNumber,
                    InsuranceNumber = x.NationalInsuranceNumber,
                    PostalCode = x.PostalCode 
                }) .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Qing suggested use ICollection or IList.

```
public ICollection<DriverDetails>  DriverDetails { get; set; }
```

Since **IEnumerable** is for iterating over collection, it does not provide you Create, Update and Delete.

ICollection or child of ICollection facilitates you with **CRUD** operation that will happen between navigation properties.